# Creating custom product page in drupal 6 using ubercart

Tags: drupal-6, e-commerce, ubercart

I am using drupal 6 and ubercart module for selling products online.
I have created a page content type and in html code i also added a the source of the buy now button from google . Now i want this button to function same as the buy now button works in product content type. Simply redirecting it to cart/checkout doesnt works

Answer (score 1):

First, there's aren't using it's cart.
All your catalogue using Views and CCK.
If you Google buy button is unique foar every good you sell you can jyst create a CCK-field to input it and render on page display.